# handle scroll on canvas view - paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

http://40.117.122.212/

I want to add more images dynamically on scrolling the canvas, i don't wanna see any empty areas on the canvas.

Any ideas on how to get that done ?

I use paperjs, I create about 90 images and they are moving on the canvas randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you scroll, you can check if there is space for more images at the bottom of the screen (and maybe at the top too for a better effect?) and if this is true, add more images.
In order to get that working, you will certainly need to find a way to quickly get the topest/lowest items to check how far they are from view bounds.

To better understand the concept, I reduced the problem to a simple case involving only one column of circles.
Here is the [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating the solution.
Code should be self-explainatory and should allow you to transpose it to your specific case.

```
// Set gris Size.
const gridSize = 100;

// Calculate and store several useful metrics.
const viewHeight = view.bounds.height;
const itemsCount = Math.floor(viewHeight / gridSize);

// For the simplicity of the demo, items are only drawn in one column so x
// coordinate is constant.
const x = view.center.x;

// Create original items to fill the screen.
let items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
    items.push(createItem(i * gridSize));
}

// Center them on the screen.
project.activeLayer.position = view.center;

// On scroll...
view.element.onmousewheel = function(event) {
    // ...translate layer up or down.
    // Using layer translation instead of view scroll cause items coordinates
    // to be updated which will help us in later calculations.
    const translation = event.deltaY > 0 ? new Point(0, 10) : new Point(0, -10);
    project.activeLayer.translate(translation);

    // Trigger items addition process.
    addItemsIfNeeded();
};

// Simply create a random colored, horizontally centered circle, at given
// y position.
function createItem(y) {
    return new Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(x, y),
        radius: gridSize / 4,
        fillColor: Color.random()
    });
}

// Check for empty space at the bottom or the top of the page and create as
// many items as needed to fill the empty space.
function addItemsIfNeeded() {
    // Get extremas items y positions.
    const lastItemY = items[items.length - 1].position.y;
    const firstItemY = items[0].position.y;
    const deltaBottom = viewHeight - lastItemY;
    // If there is empty space at bottom...
    if (deltaBottom > gridSize) {
        // ...add items at bottom.
        const itemsNeededCount = Math.floor(deltaBottom / gridSize);
        addItems(itemsNeededCount, lastItemY);
    // If there is empty space at top...
    } else if (firstItemY > gridSize) {
        // ...add items at top.
        const itemsNeededCount = Math.floor(firstItemY / gridSize);
        addItems(itemsNeededCount, firstItemY, true);
    }
}

// Create given number of items and add them to the begining or the end of the
// stack.
function addItems(count, referenceItemY, before) {
    // For each new item...
    for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        // ...calculate y position...
        const y = before
            ? referenceItemY - i * gridSize
            : referenceItemY + i * gridSize;
        // ...create item...
        const item = createItem(y);
        // ...add it to the stack.
        if (before) {
            items.unshift(item);
        } else {
            items.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```